# Append Angular component with javascript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, leaflet

I ask a question that it has been answered already here, but I think my particular case make things a little bit more complicated. Here's the thing.

I'm using Angular2 and I'm creating several components (component to display a Card, Carousel, tooltip..ecc..). Each component has its own tag that I use to place it inside my templates file. Everything is ok.
Here an example:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-card',
templateUrl: './tb-card.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tb-card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent {
    @Input() image: string;
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() subtitle: string;
}
```

Now. I have a Google Map and everytime a user clicks on the map, I want to display a popup inside this map. The content of this popup should be an angular component, so I do this (using the API of the map).

```
 map.popup().setLatLng([pos.lat, pos.lng])
  .setContent('<app-card title="this is a title" subtitle="this is asubtitle"></app-card>');
```

Of course, the app-card tag is not processed by the angular engine. The same problem happens if I just append an app-card component with jquery.

I saw other questions **similar** to this one that says that I should use a ComponentResolver ([How can I inject an AngularJS 2 component dynamically in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947411/how-can-i-inject-an-angularjs-2-component-dynamically-in-jquery))

The problem is: that example start with the idea that there is a "main" component (called Dynamic component) that it is already inside the DOM and I should use this component as a "bridge" to inject other components. But I don't have it (I'm inside a Google Map). Unless I put this component somewhere on my page and I do detach and attach in the map, but I don't really like this trick.

Did anyone have my same problem? 
Thank you so much to everyone who will help me! :)

Comment: Is this a leaflet concern? the code you posted seems to be the leaflet popup function.

Comment: Hi henrisycip, thanks for your answer! Yes, it is leaflet. But here the problem is not Google Map or leaflet. As I wrote, you can easily reproduce the problem just using jquery and appending an element dynamically inside the DOM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922224/angular2-component-into-dynamicaly-created-element/40926110#40926110

Comment: Thank you so much @yurzui !! It seems exactly what I was looking for! I'll give it a try and I'll let you know! :)

Comment: @yurzui It worked like a charm! Thank you so much! If you answer the question I would be glad to accept it!